# Proper way of loading model and apply predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

model4 is a Naive Bayes Model and used split with test_size=0.22 , the code should load the model apply predictions based of trained model then save it as column with the rest of the data.

```
joblib.dump(model4, 'training1.joblib')
# ------------------------loading model-------------------------------
data = pd.read_csv('Documents_data.csv')
model = joblib.load('training1.joblib')
X_all = pandas.get_dummies(data.drop(['score', 'size', 'created', 'user'], axis=1))
y_all = data['score']
pred = model.predict(X_all)
data['prediction'] = pred
data.to_csv('predictions.csv', index=False)
```

Usually i use (X_test) for prediction like:

```
pred = model4.predict(X_test)
```

I tried to split data again :

```
# ------------------------loading model-------------------------------
data = pd.read_csv('Documents_data.csv')
model = joblib.load('training1.joblib')
X_all = pandas.get_dummies(data.drop(['score', 'size', 'created', 'user'], axis=1))
y_all = data['score']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, test_size=0.22, random_state=0)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
data['prediction'] = pred
data.to_csv('predictions.csv', index=False)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coldtea\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\machine_learning.py", line 169, in <module>
    data['prediction'] = pred
  File "C:\Users\coldtea\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\coldtea\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3242, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\coldtea\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\coldtea\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 751, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (42) does not match length of index (190)
```

at least can someone provide an example with similar requirements?

Comment: Please show the traceback for the error too.

Comment: Your error is here I guess: `data['prediction'] = pred` your `data` and `pred` is having different number of rows

Comment: @Pygirl in training i used test_size=0.22 is that means it can predict only 22% of the data ?  
sorry I'm new to machine learning...

Comment: Show the completed traceback please, this could be very useful.

Comment: `X_test['prediction'] = pred` ??? why you are using `data`??

Comment: @Pygirl to apply the trained model on new set of data(here i used same csv) , is that correct or i misunderstood the purpose of loading this model??

Comment: actually you train your model on the training set and then you take the unseen data and make prediction on that. Since you already have trained data I assume it must have been trained on some other data so now your are trying to make prediction. So why you are going for splitting?

Comment: @Pygirl to get (X_test) ,is it same as X_all ??

Comment: yes but see you are using `pd.get_dummies` it will create an issue. The processing steps that you are taking for your test data should be purely based on your train data. I mean you will do `fit_transform(train_data)` and then `transform(test_data)`

Comment: @Pygirl i used (pd.get_dummies) also on trained data because their is columns contains strings like (file path),(process name) and Boolean , yes i did "Feature Scaling"  StandardScaler() fit_transform and transform ... should i send the full code??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232647/discussion-between-coldtea-and-pygirl).